# Address where an element just past the end of an array would be stored

Tags: c#, .net, clr, il

According to ECMA-335:

> **II.14.4.2 Managed pointers**
>
> Managed pointers (&) can point to an instance of a value type, a field of an object, a field of a value
> type, an element of an array, or the **address where an element just past the end of an array would be
> stored (for pointer indexes into managed arrays)**.

The last part interests me. Does it mean that a reference beyond the end of an array is valid? How is such a reference obtained (possibly with IL)? How does the CLR handle reading and writing there?

Comment: Yes, the reference is valid.  Dereferencing the pointer is not.  Otherwise very common behavior, also used in C++ for example, the end() function of a collection class returns it.  The GC can deal with this, an object reference does not point to the start of the object so the end() pointer cannot be confused with another object.

Comment: @HansPassant Does the dereferencing throw an exception or something else?

Comment: Pointer dereferencing is not checked, the odds for an AccessViolationException are pretty low.  Not zero.  You just get garbage.

Comment: I tried getting a managed pointer past a 1-element array `x` using `f(ref x[1])`. It compiled into [`ldelema`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldelema), which threw `IndexOutOfRangeException`, as documented. So I have no idea how to get a managed pointer that points past the end of the array.

Comment: @svick I tried loading a pointer to the last element with `ldelema` and then adding the size of the element to it. Dereferencing works and produces garbage.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Interesting. `add` does support managed pointers, but doing so is not verifiable (§III.1.5).

Comment: @svick Yeah, that's why I thought there would be another way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the pointer is valid, but it does not mean that dereferencing it is valid.

For instance, if you have an array containing 10 Int32 values, which means 10 * 4 bytes, a pointer to the 40th byte after the start of the array is valid.

Dereferencing it isn't.

Which means reading or writing that location is not valid.

Comment: I wonder how the GC can tell that this pointer belongs to the array and not to the object that immediately follows the array in memory.

Comment: It doesn't. Pointers doesn't keep objects alive, references do.

Comment: But managed pointers need to be adjusted when objects move. These are  non-pinned interior pointers, right?

Comment: It's trivial at the IL level. `ref` is implemented using interior pointers.

Comment: In the documentation the instruction that is used for `ref` (to array elements) returns a "managed pointer". This is a non-pinned interior pointer. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldelema%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Two objects are not completely adjacent in memory in terms of memory you can legally point to, there's overhead where no legal pointer is allowed to point, containing things like pointers to vtable and similar.

Answer (score 2):

Think about segmented 'protected' memory.

The statement you quoted is echoing the C++ standard, that goes into some detail about how the pointer-past-the-end must be valid and safe to compare to. 
A large part of the C++ library (algorithms) uses this kind of pointers as 'sentinel', equivalent with for example EOF.

With protected memory, just loading a pointer value outside your process space into a register could lead to a protection fault. It won't wait for a dereference.

What is actually being said here is that the last byte of your data may not be the last byte of an allocated segment. The memory manager will have to pad with 1 or more bytes. Thus allowing the compiler/optimizer to always use an address register for pointers.